# Why does a small change to this Scala code make such a huge difference to performance?

Tags: performance, optimization, scala

I'm running on a 32-bit [Debian 6.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian#2005.E2.80.93present) (Squeeze) system (a 2.5 GHz [Core 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Core_2) CPU), sun-java6 6.24-1 but with the Scala 2.8.1 packages from Wheezy.

This code, compiled with `scalac -optimise`, takes over 30 seconds to run:

```
object Performance {

  import scala.annotation.tailrec

  @tailrec def gcd(x:Int,y:Int):Int = {
    if (x == 0)
      y 
    else 
      gcd(y%x,x)
  }

  val p = 1009
  val q = 3643
  val t = (p-1)*(q-1)

  val es = (2 until t).filter(gcd(_,t) == 1)
  def main(args:Array[String]) {
    println(es.length)
  }
}
```

But if I make the trivial change of moving the `val es=` one line down and inside the scope of `main`, then it runs in just 1 second, which is much more like I was expecting to see and comparable with the performance of equivalent C++. Interestingly, leaving the `val es=` where it is but qualifying it with `lazy` also has the same accelerating effect.

What's going on here? Why is performing the calculation outside function scope so much slower?

Comment: I see the same thing in 2.8.1 (Sun Java 1.6.0_24-b07) without `-optimize`, FWIW.

Comment: Mentioning optimize at all was a bit of a red herring sorry; I've never actually seen using it (or not) make any significant difference to the performance of any Scala stuff I've worked on.

Comment: interesting...the same thing happens on a similar system with scala 2.9.0 with and without -optimize.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The JVM doesn't optimize static initializers (which is what this is) to the same level that it optimizes method calls.  Unfortunately, when you do a lot of work there, that hurts performance--this is a perfect example of that.  This is also one reason why the old `Application` trait was considered problematic, and why there is in Scala 2.9 a `DelayedInit` trait that gets a bit of compiler help to move stuff from the initializer into a method that's called later on.

---

(Edit: fixed "constructor" to "initializer".  Rather lengthy typo!)

Comment: Is that something Scala specific or generally true? Because I don't see why the JIT wouldn't optimize long static initializers in normal java code (or to be more exact why it would distinguish between static code blocks and normal)

Comment: @Voo, this is true in general, and affect even Java static codes.  It seems that it is a JVM design; one possible hypothesis: given static initializers only run once, the JVM authors didn't want to invest as much time optimizing their use case.

Comment: @Rex Kerr, would changing the code to `class Performance` and `object Performance extends Performance` also make optimizable?

Comment: @pedrofurla - No, it's still executed in a static context.  What you are suggesting is what the old `Application` trait was doing.  If you turned it into a `lazy val` it would probably work in this case, since it wouldn't be evaluated until it was needed in the `main` method.

Comment: Yes simply changing the declaration to lazy speeds it up just as much as moving the declaration into main (and given that lazy does the job, I'm a little surprised there's considered to also be an additional need for something like DelayedInit).

Comment: @timday - Adding lazy to every single expensive computation gets tiring after a while.  It's nice to have a mechanism to do it all at once.

Comment: @notnoop I don't see why. Sure the static initializer isn't optimized - just as any main method that is only called once won't be. But if we have some complex computation inside why wouldn't that be JITed according to the usual rules as usual?

Comment: @notnoop.  Static Initializers on other hand can really only be run once (per ClassLoader) and have non-trivial semantics: Check JLS 12.4.2.  The JVM designers basically decided it wasn't worth the effort.  The main method on the other require a lot of optimizations to actually make the code faster.  Also, the `main` method just like any other static method can actually run multiple times (you can actually call the main method yourself.. shocking!).

Answer (score 41):

Code inside a top-level object block is translated to a static initializer on the object's class.  The equivalent in Java would be

```
class Performance{
    static{
      //expensive calculation
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
      //use result of expensive calculation
    }
}
```

The HotSpot JVM doesn't perform any optimizations on code encountered during static initializers, under the reasonable heuristic that such code will only be run once.

Comment: Yes this is fascinating.  I come to this with the perspective of someone who last touched Java in the mid 90s, but was lured back to the JVM by Scala being a much more attractive language (to me anyway) than Java.  So I do tend to get a nasty surprise when the realities of the underlying technology are unexpectedly revealed by things like this.

Comment: Especially with immutability, I suspect it to be a common pattern to do much computation inside the initialization phase of a class.

Comment: @ziggystar - This specifically affects _static_ initializers.

Comment: And since it only affects static initializers, it only affects Scala singleton objects, not class objects